# How to process each item differently in a Observable stream(RxJava)

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java

Let me put an example: Given the stream of numbers from 1 to 10, process even and odd numbers differently. Process odd numbers in a different thread and apply this transformation to them (2 * i). Process even numbers in the main thread and apply this transformation to them (2 * i - 1). The subscriber is below:

```
finalObservable.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
   @Override
   public void call(Integer t) {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + t);
   }});
```

The output should be

```
Thread-1 2
main 3
Thread-1 6
main 7
Thread-1 10
main 11
Thread-1 14
main 15
Thread-1 18
main 19
```

How to do this using RxJava-Observables operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant way to handle this problem is to use `share()` operator of the `Observable`. In a huuuuge simplification it lets you split your `observable` into multiple ones. So in your case, an observable representing a stream of numbers, can be split into two observables. One for odd numbers and one for even numbers.

Assuming `allNumbers` (in your example `finalObservable`) represents the <1, 10> numbers stream:

```
final Observable<Integer> allNumbers =
        Observable.from(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
                .share();
Observable<Integer> oddNumbers = allNumbers.filter(new Func1<Integer, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(Integer integer) {
        return integer % 2 != 0;
    }
});
Observable<Integer> evenNumbers = allNumbers.filter(new Func1<Integer, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(Integer integer) {
        return integer % 2 == 0;
    }
});

final Action1<Integer> printingAction = new Action1<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Integer t) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + t);
    }
};

evenNumbers.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(printingAction);
oddNumbers.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(printingAction);
```

---

And simplified with Retrolambda:

```
final Observable<Integer> allNumbers =
        Observable.from(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
                .share();
Observable<Integer> oddNumbers = allNumbers.filter(integer -> integer % 2 != 0);
Observable<Integer> evenNumbers = allNumbers.filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0);

final Action1<Integer> printingAction = 
         t -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + t);

evenNumbers.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(printingAction);
oddNumbers.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(printingAction);
```

---

You didn't specify **exactly** what needs to be processed in which thread, so you might need to correct `subscribeOn` arguments and maybe add `observeOn` operators. Depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Yes this works fine. I have one more query. Instead of subscribing to 2 different observables, is there a way to merge the Observables such that the output is in same order as the input?

Comment: You can use `Observable.merge`, but the whole idea is that with two different observables you can treat them differently thread-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea will be something like this (using `flatMap`):

```java
Observable.from(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
          .flatMap(number -> {
              if (number % 2 == 0) {
                  return Observable.just(2 * number - 1);
              } else {
                  return Observable.fromCallable(() -> 2 * number)
                                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
              }
          })
          .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
              @Override
              public void call(Integer integer) {
                  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + integer);
              }
          });
```

Comment: I have a difficult time knowing when to use flatmap vs map, but why can't you just map to `return 2*number`, for example?

Comment: @cricket_007 that's right, we could if only we didn't have to use different threads for different values

Comment: I figured that had something to do with it. I'm guessing running the thread from the subscribe is bad practice?

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean changing thread with non-reactive instruments but rather pure Java? You can do it, but it's not going to look this nice.

Comment: I was just curious if it were possible. I'm still getting the hang of Rx :)